# JPA, Spring, Eclipse, Hibernate, DB2, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.persistence.Convert

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am creating a new project to use Spring, JPA, Hibernate and DB2. I'm running my application on Websphere Community Server(3.0). I have set up the Java configuration and XML Config for my repository. When I run my application, during the app load I get the error:

```
2014-12-03 23:54:48,532 WARN  [XmlWebApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myEmf' defined in class path resource [repo-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.persistence.Convert
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext.access$201(GeronimoStandardContext.java:121)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext$SystemMethodValve.invoke(GeronimoStandardContext.java:723)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.invoke(GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.java:48)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.ProtectedTargetValve.invoke(ProtectedTargetValve.java:53)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext.startInternal(GeronimoStandardContext.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatContainer.addContext(TomcatContainer.java:310)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatWebAppContext.doStart(TomcatWebAppContext.java:567)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.createInstance(GBeanInstance.java:1000)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:271)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.start(GBeanInstance.java:555)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.attemptFullStart(GBeanDependency.java:110)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.addTarget(GBeanDependency.java:145)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency$1.running(GBeanDependency.java:119)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:176)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.access$300(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:45)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor$RawLifecycleBroadcaster.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:254)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:301)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.startRecursive(GBeanInstanceState.java:127)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.startRecursive(GBeanInstance.java:569)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.startRecursiveGBean(BasicKernel.java:386)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.ConfigurationUtil.startConfigurationGBeans(ConfigurationUtil.java:466)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.KernelConfigurationManager.start(KernelConfigurationManager.java:225)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:710)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:131)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:883)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:245)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.KernelGBean.invoke(KernelGBean.java:344)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:131)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:883)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:245)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.jmx.MBeanGBeanBridge.invoke(MBeanGBeanBridge.java:172)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:480)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1498)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:108)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1339)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:366)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1438)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:859)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:339)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:189)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:186)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:366)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:185)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:823)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.persistence.Convert
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.source.annotations.JPADotNames.<clinit>(JPADotNames.java:134)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.prepareMetadataSources(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Convert
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.apache.geronimo.hook.equinox.GeronimoClassLoader.loadClass(GeronimoClassLoader.java:85)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:707)
    ... 98 more
```

At this moment, I'm using the XML config. The java configuration also gives me the same error.

And this is my XML Config file.

```
<bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.rionegro.model" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/MYSDB1:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;" />
    <property name="username" value="db2inst1" />
    <property name="password" value="333333" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So Hibernate expects JPA 2.1 and you only provide JPA 2.0 (or less) API jar. Put JPA API 2.1 in the CLASSPATH and remove all older versions. As can be seen on many other posts on Stackoverflow.